# How to add more input names in js?

Tags: javascript

How can you add another name to the input names ?

```
  var checked = document.querySelector("input[name = 'variable']:checked")
```

I have another input name called 'sub'. But I don't know how you can add this in the code.

(I am in the learning process of js)

```
<h1>Quiz</h1>
  <form id="form1" action=" ">
      <div class="row"> <h3>Moths are a member of what order?</h3></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Octagon <span class="explanation" id="demo" style="color:red"></span></div>
      <div> </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Leprosy <span class="explanation" id="demo2" style="color:red"></span></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Lepidoptera <span class="explanation" id="demo3" style="color:green"></span></div>
      &nbsp;
     <div class="row"> <h3>Question 2</h3></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1 <span class="explanation" id="demo4"></span> </div> 
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2</div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3</div>
```

and the script:

```
function myFunction() {

        var explanations = document.querySelectorAll(".explanation");
        for(var x = 0; x < explanations.length; x++) {
          explanations[x].innerHTML = "";
        }

        var checked = document.querySelector("input[name=variable]:checked, input[name=sub]:checked")
        var value = checked.parentNode.lastChild.id;
        var answer;
        switch (value) {
          case 'demo':
            answer = "An octagon is an object with 8 sides to it";
            break;
          case 'demo2':
            answer = "Leprosy is a chronic infection";
            break;
          case 'demo3':
            answer = "Yes ! this is correct";  
            break;
            case 'demo4':
            answer = "hjhjhjhjct";  
            break;
        }
        checked.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: I hope you this example your help full try this https://plnkr.co/edit/OvcwBzfFte4A0F0NbNSi?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you ?

Comment: Try: `"input[name=variable]:checked, input[name=sub]:checked"`

Comment: Hi Washington, I used your code. The variable still works, only the sub doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, should work. Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Yep, I edited my post now. You can see the html and script now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some points to mention:

**First.**

```
<div class="row">
    <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />Octagon <span class="explanation" id="demo" style="color:red"></span></div>
  <div> </div> <-- this is will become your .lastChild so i think you not expect this <div> as .lastChild so delete that tag.
```

**Second** use querySelectorAll for multiple selection, so this is wrong:

```
var checked = document.querySelector("input[name=variable]:checked, input[name=sub]:checked")
```

**Third** multiple select returns mutiple result, i.e. array of result, so use array to result handling.

Below is edited code, so reedit it for your purpose:

```html
<style>
  .quizbox {
    width: 58%;
    max-width: 950px;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #00A7AE;
    margin-top: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: #73B7DB;
  }
  
  
  .row {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
  
  span#demo, #demo2, #demo3, #demo4, #demo5, #demo6, #demo7, #demo8, #demo9 {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 30%;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
  }
  
input[type="submit"]
               {
padding: 10px 15px 11px !important;
font-size: 18px !important;
background-color: #57d6c7;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
</style>


<div class="quizbox">

  <!-- open main div -->
  <h1>Quiz</h1>
  <form id="form1" action=" ">
      <div class="row"><h3>Moths are a member of what order?</h3></div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />
        Octagon <span class="explanation" id="demo1" style="color:red"></span></div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="0" />
        Leprosy <span class="explanation" id="demo2" style="color:red"></span></div>
        
      <div class="row">
        <input name="variable" type="radio" value="33" />Lepidoptera <span class="explanation" id="demo3" style="color:green"></span></div>
      &nbsp;
     <div class="row"> <h3>Question 2</h3></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 1 <span class="explanation" id="demo4"></span></div> 
        
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 2 <span class="explanation" id="demo5"></span></div>
        
      <div class="row">
        <input name="sub" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3 <span class="explanation" id="demo6"></span></div>
      &nbsp;
      <div class="row"><h3>Question 3</h3></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 1 <span class="explanation" id="demo7"></span></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="33" />Answer 2 <span class="explanation" id="demo8"></span></div>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="con" type="radio" value="0" />Answer 3 <span class="explanation" id="demo9"></span></div>
   <p> <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Check" /> </p>
  </form>
 

</div>
<!-- close quizbox div -->
<script>
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
     

      return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
    } //this ends the submit function
  function myFunction() {
    
            var explanations = document.querySelectorAll(".explanation");
            for(var x = 0; x < explanations.length; x++) {
              explanations[x].innerHTML = "";
            }

            var checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=variable]:checked, input[name=sub]:checked, input[name=con]:checked")
   for(var answ = 0 ; answ < checked.length; answ++){
    var value = checked[answ].parentNode.lastChild.id;
    var answer;
    switch (value) {
      case 'demo':
     answer = "An octagon is an object with 8 sides to it";
     break;
      case 'demo2':
     answer = "Leprosy is a chronic infection";
     break;
      case 'demo3':
     answer = "Yes ! this is correct";  
     break;
      case 'demo4':
     answer = "demo4";  
     break;
      case 'demo5':
     answer = "demo5";  
     break;
      case 'demo6':
     answer = "demo6";  
     break;
      case 'demo7':
     answer = "demo7";  
     break;
      case 'demo8':
     answer = "demo8";  
     break;
      case 'demo9':
     answer = "demo9";  
     break;
    }
    checked[answ].parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML = answer;
   }
    }
</script>
<div> </div>
```

Comment: Very good explanation Elnur, and it worked. Much appreciated !